# Conda reports that a package is installed, but it appears not to be

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, spacy

I'm trying to install spaCy using conda but i still getting the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'
```

Things i already tried:

1. re installing conda.
2. delete and create a new environment.

OBS:

1. the environment is active.
2. running Linux.
3. if i run `!conda list` i can see to spaCy package.

**I thing the problem is about the installation directory, but i'm not sure how to solve it.**

some output:

```
    import sys
    print(sys.prefix)
    output: /usr

  active environment : Texto
    active env location : /home/arancium/.conda/envs/Texto
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /home/arancium/.condarc
 populated config files : /etc/conda/condarc
                          /home/arancium/miniforge3/.condarc
                          /home/arancium/.condarc
          conda version : 23.1.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.10.9.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __glibc=2.37=0
                          __linux=6.2.8=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /home/arancium/miniforge3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/arancium/miniforge3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/arancium/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/arancium/.conda/envs
                          /home/arancium/miniforge3/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/23.1.0 requests/2.28.2 CPython/3.10.9 Linux/6.2.8-zen1-1-zen arch/rolling glibc/2.37
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
Texto                 *  /home/arancium/.conda/envs/Texto
base                     /home/arancium/miniforge3

sys.version: 3.10.9 | packaged by conda-forge | (main...
sys.prefix: /home/arancium/miniforge3
sys.executable: /home/arancium/miniforge3/bin/python
conda location: /home/arancium/miniforge3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda
conda-build: None
conda-env: /home/arancium/miniforge3/bin/conda-env
user site dirs: ~/.local/lib/python3.10

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: Texto
CONDA_EXE: /home/arancium/miniforge3/bin/conda
CONDA_PREFIX: /home/arancium/.conda/envs/Texto
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER: (Texto) 
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: /home/arancium/miniforge3/bin/python
CONDA_ROOT: /home/arancium/miniforge3
CONDA_SHLVL: 1
CUDA_PATH: /opt/cuda
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
LD_PRELOAD: <not set>
PATH: /home/arancium/.conda/envs/Texto/bin:/home/arancium/miniforge3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/cuda/bin:/opt/cuda/nsight_compute:/opt/cuda/nsight_systems/bin:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
XDG_SEAT_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_SESSION_PATH: /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python interpreter you are using is not the one from your active `conda` environment.

Lets ensure that you are using the correct Python interpreter from your active conda environment.

first activate your `conda` env `conda activate Texto` then check your python interpreter `which python` it should be something like `/home/arancium/.conda/envs/Texto/bin/python` if not make sure that make sure your `PATH` environment variable is correctly set. You can update it like that `export PATH="/home/arancium/.conda/envs/Texto/bin:$PATH"` Now run your script with the correct interpreter `python your_script.py`

If that still dont work use the full path like this `/home/arancium/.conda/envs/Texto/bin/python your_script.py`

Comment: The problem is what you say. But to make it simpler its better to (with the env active): 
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=spaCy
and then change the kernel on jupyter-lab